# jQuery Show/Hide & Css Changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm just new at jQuery, very well on css.
I'm in kind of problem. couldn't figure out.

There is a link and i want to do something when clicked like below.

```
when
clicked -> sidebar:display:none; , content:margin-left:0;
clicked again -> sidebar:display:block, content:margin-left:250px;

if screen resolutions small then 760px
clicked -> sidebar:display:block; content:margin-left:250px;
clicked again -> sidebar:display:none; content:margin-left:0;
```

pretty much like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to change visible and margin:

```
$("#sidebar").click(function(){
    if($("#sidebar").css('display') == 'none' ){
        $("#sidebar").hide();
        $("#content").css( "margin-left", "0px" );
    }else {
       $("#sidebar").show();
       $("#content").css( "margin-left", "250px" );
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery you can show hide an element by ID easily using

```
$('#element').toggle();
```

so put this in a click event

```
$('#buttonID').click(function() {
    $('#elementID').toggle()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use css

HTML

```
<label for="toggle-1"> click me </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">  
<div class="Content"> Content</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Checkbox Hack */

input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}
label { 
  -webkit-appearance: push-button;
  -moz-appearance: button; 
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
    border:none;
}

/* Default State */
.Content {
   background: green;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
    margin-left:250px;
   line-height: 100px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .Content {
   display: none;
   margin-left:0
}
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    .Content {
   background: green;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   display: none;
   margin-left:0px;
   line-height: 100px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .Content {
   display: block;
    margin-left:250px;
}
}
```

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8etcghv8/)